# Considering recessed lights in walk in shower

Tags: lighting, shower

In the process of converting tub/shower area to a walk-in shower and want to consider recessed lighting in that area, Somewhat familiar with code,,, would it simplify situation if low voltage lighting was used?

Answer (score 1):

No it would not. You just need to make sure your recessed luminaires are rated for wet location.  As a side note if you have a combo luminaire with a exhaust fan then that would need to be GFCI protected, but just a luminaire with no exhaust fan then that does not need to be GFCI protected.